# C# : make derived object conditionally share same base object

Tags: c#, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have a base class with is inherited by multiple derived classes. I am initializing some properties of base class in constructor. Is there any way i can make the base class property being shared by my derived objects rather than creating the same property values for each derived class object. This is really important because some of the base class property values are generated by services and sharing this can improve performance. 
Below is somewhat a simple blueprint of what i am trying to say:

```
public class ClassA
{
    //i dont want to use static here as it will be shared for multiple codes
    protected string country { get; set; }
    public ClassA(string code)
    {
        country = CallsomeService(code);
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public ClassB(string code) : base(code)
    {
        //blah blah
    }

    public void DomeSomethingWithCountry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"doing this with {country} in classB");
    }
}

public class ClassC : ClassA
{
    public ClassC(string code) : base(code)
    {
        //blah blah
    }

    public void DomeSomethingWithCountry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"doing soemthing else with {country} in classC");
    }
}
```

Now making objects like below

```
     public void test()
        {
            //call service for this
            var classb=new ClassB("1");
            //dont call service for this
            var classc=new ClassC("1");
classb.DomeSomethingWithCountry();
classc.DomeSomethingWithCountry();
            //call service for this as code is different
            var classb1=new ClassB("2");
        }
```

Comment: If i make it static for all codes it will return always the same country

Comment: Pass one instance of an object in the constructor that holds the `Value` _(cache)_

Comment: @SwagataPrateek these base class properties will be used only by the derived class methods

Comment: @Unnie took a while for me to understand. Took off my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the *result* of having made the call statically, rather than the value itself.

```
public class ClassA
{
    static Dictionary<string,string> codeToCountryLookup
         = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    protected string country { get; set; }
    public ClassA(string code)
    {
       if(!codeToCountryLookup.ContainsKey(code))
            codeToCountryLookup.Add(code,CallsomeService(code));
       country = codeToCountryLookup[code];
    }
}
```

This is not in any way threadsafe, but should give you somewhere to start.

Comment: What if he locks one object before checking if dictionary contains certain key ? That can help with the multi-threading right ?

Comment: Yes, its just that properly handing multi-threading situations is well outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: this looks a good option to start with. I have updated my post. What if i am using this country property in my derived class methods. Then how can i efficiently refer this right country in derived class methods

Comment: @Unnie I have changed nothing about the field `country` in your base class. You can continue to use it as you did before.

Comment: Although this will work, I wonder if the proper place for the caching is at the service level, rather than at the class level.

Comment: @JimMischel I agree.